# Adding HTML content to jQuery parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript function that gets a parameter which is initialized as follows:

In some Javascript class:

```
var element = new Element('li');
element.addClass('section');
element.addClass('section-' + r);
element.setStyle('width', this.sumWidth);
this.ulBody.appendChild(li2);
this.options.load({parent: element});
```

I've passed my js function to the class above (I reach the code below when the class above runs):

```
function load(params){

}
```

My question is how I can add HTML content to the params.parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

```
params.parent.innerHTML='<h1>your html</h1>'
```